# How to implement Runtime for movies in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a `Movie` class and I need to define the `Runtime`, for say 2h 15mn 45s for each movie. Is there a built in type in the `BCL` for this?

If not, what type should I define for this? Should it be called `Interval` or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `System.TimeSpan` struct.

Comment: PSHAW!  Why use a language built-in when you can write your own? ;)